# How to know if Internet Explorer in Windows 7 runs with Administrative Privileges?

Tags: windows-7, activex, uac, administration

I use IE on Windows 7(With UAC) to run some ActiveX that installs our client product.
My problem is that I want to check if the explorer runs with administrative privileges prior to ActiveX installation, and if not to pop message box to our clients that they need to run the IE with 'Run As Administrator'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The user doesn't *have* to run Internet Explorer as in administrative use.

Inside your digitally signed `cab` file, you will have an `.inf` file that will instruct Internet Explorer to register the ActiveX:

**CohenSoft.inf**:

```
[version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
AdvancedINF=2.0

[Add.Code]
CohenSoft.ocx=CohenSoft.ocx

[CohenSoft.ocx]
file-win32-x86=thiscab
clsid={de8530cf-d204-4877-9cab-f052bf1f661f}
FileVersion=1,12,47,660
RegisterServer=yes
```

Internet Explorer will *automatically* prompt the user for UAC elevation:

[image]

And your ActiveX will be installed as an administrator.